# Angular, Cannot make an an API call probably because of CORS issue

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am trying to make an Angular application consuming Foreign Exchange (forex) market API.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=[MY ACCESS KEY]'
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);  
})
```

I keep getting the following error when I look at the browser console.

> Request header field `Authorization` is not allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in preflight response.

The weirdest part is that it used to work - I was able to retrieve JSON info from the API call without a problem, but it does not any more.

Is there anyone who can point me to a set of possible causes? Would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything in your code (say, the path for the api) then it must be one of two thing:

- The browser configuration has changed
- The api provider has blocked cross domain request, you should contact him, maybe he require callback with jsonp ajax request

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kobi In fact, I tried $http.jsonp, and the error message has gone but I got a new one: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token." I inspected the corresponding link/line, and I found that the error was caused by a line on JSON response.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token is a syntex error in your code. check your code syntex. it has nothing to do with the response

Comment: Unexpected token was indicating this line: {"success":true,"terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms","privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy","timestamp":1461182237,"source":"USD","quotes":{"USDAED":3.673103,"USDAFN":68.339996,"USDALL":121.709503,...} It was not my code. I know Uncaught SyntaxError is usually caused by my code, but in this case it was not. The error was indicating the actual JSON response. Isn't it weird. This problem consumed me for 2 days.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : <<--- this was the exact error message. It seems indicating the colon after "success"